# How to add ripple effect with gradient to button?

Tags: android, button, gradient, ripple

I created a button and I want to add ripple effect and gradient to that button!

Here is my Button code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/percentageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="%"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30dp">
</Button>
```

Here is my gradient.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:gradientRadius="100"
        android:centerX="49%"
        android:centerY="50%"
        android:centerColor="#434343"
        android:startColor="#0F0F0F"
        android:endColor="#141414"
        android:type="radial"/>
  </shape>
```

I have tried all the possibilities but not getting how to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

To get the ripple effect when you press a button, simply change your button xml to include:

`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

and to have a basic gradient on your button you can have:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="-90"
            android:startColor="COLORHERE"
            android:endColor="COLORHERE"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: not a preferred solution as android:foreground required api level 23 minimum

Answer (score 5):

`android:foreground` didn't work for me in Lollipop and here are my xml drawable for the button.
Add `button_background.xml` to your drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:type="linear" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Add this to the background of your button.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```

**Note** :
Attribute **android:foreground** has no effect on **API** levels lower than **23**

Comment: You sure that this works? I tried it and the part with the android:id/mask isn't being executed . When clicked the color set inside the "ripple" tag is being set. I also tried setting it to transparent to get the gradient, but also not working (just the "normal" state is being displayed correctly)